# How to combine bxslider and lightbox?

Tags: jquery, lightbox, conflict, bxslider

On my page I have a little bxlider and I want to open a lightbox gallery when clicking on one of the slides but there are conflicts when using these two scripts. jQuery's noConflict() won't help in that case. Anyone know's how to fix this or a lightbox similiar library that works together with the bxslider?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. My lightbox version was too old. With the [current version](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) it works.

The slides list has the following form:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
   <li><a href="link-to-the-image.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-name"><img alt="" src="link-to-the-image.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul>
```